# How to change the DXTabControl Background Color at WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, tabcontrol

I have a DXTabControl at WPF C# and I want to change the Background Color of the DXTabControl.
How can I do that?

[image]

XAML CODE

```
<dx:DXTabControl>
<dx:DXTabItem  Header="System" Margin="0">
    <dxe:TextEdit x:Name="txtChargeNo"  Background="#D5D6D8"  ShowNullText="True" NullText="Sarj No"  Height="30" FontSize="16"/>
</dx:DXTabItem>
<dx:DXTabItem x:Name="tbPast" Header="Past">
</dx:DXTabItem>
```

Comment: where are you setting background color of Tab.. I am not able to see anywhere in the xaml code.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
<dx:DXTabControl Padding="0">
    <dx:DXTabItem Header="tab">
        <Border Background="Red">
            <TextBlock Text="Tab content"/>
        </Border>
    </dx:DXTabItem>
</dx:DXTabControl>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks,but that solution doesnt works.